# Visual Studio 2017 is preparing tests longer than expected

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2017

From one moment (not fixed when it happened, probably, when I moved some test projects to another folder on disk) Visual Studio is taking longer than expected when I open Test Explorer and want to run tests. It takes minutes like this:

[image]

Why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: @mjwills till 5 minutes (CPU i7-4770, 24 Gb RAM). Expect... till 10 sec :) It was some seconds 1 week ago...

Comment: If you build your Solution do the tests appear?

Comment: @mjwills, no...